# url.Action open link in new window on ASP.NET MVC Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying open a new window using url.Action.
And the new Window url is out of this current project(external website).

Here are two things i need to do:

1. I need to open it in a new window.
2. It is going to `http://localhost:57391/Home/http:/www.yahoo.com`  instead of directly to Yahoo.

Here is my code:

```
<tr >
       <td>                    
        <a href="<%= Url.Action("http://www.yahoo.com") %>"><span>Go to Yahoo</span></a> 
         </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need to use the helper methods at all:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank"><span>Go to Yahoo</span></a>
```

`Html.Action` is only for controller actions, which an external link is not. There's nothing wrong with using plain HTML to link with.

Comment: Completely right, as a side note: in case it was a real controller action: <a href="<%= Url.Action("http://www.yahoo.com") %>" target="_blank"> could have been used of course! The Url.Action only fills in the href part, the rest of the anchor is still free to decorate with whatever attributes you'd like.

Comment: Or `@Html.ActionLink("New report", "New", "Report", null, new {target = "_blank"})` Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790355/asp-net-mvc-3-controller-action-and-open-new-window

Answer (score 3):

You can try doing something like this

`<a href="http://@Model.Link" target="_blank"><span>@Model.Link</span></a>`

Answer (score -1):

If the website parameter is dynamic -or- attaching from Model, we can try something like this.

```
<a href="@Model.Website" target="_blank">@Model.Website</a>
```

Comment: This solution goes to http://localhost:57391/Home/http:/www.yahoo.com. @santan's solution works "<a href="http://@Model.Link" target="_blank"><span>@Model.Link</span></a>"