# ASP.Net MVC 3 Controller Action and Open New Window

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, action

i have a controller and an action. this action is to save data into database. and now, i want when i submit a button, my controller do an action and open new window.

```
public ActionResult New(FormCollection collection)
    {

       data.Population_Code = collection["Countrys[0].CountryCode"];
       data.Population_Desc = collection["Countrys[0].CountryDesc"];
       data.Population_Grouping = collection["Countrys[0].CountryGroup"];
       data.Population_Type = "CNTRY";
       data.Population_Redudant = "N";
       data.Population_Modified_At = officeCode.User_Office.ToString();
       db.SaveChanges();

      //example for new window
      //window.open('/Report/New.aspx')

      return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
```

so my controller do an action and open a new window.

anyone can help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Technically, this can be done by returning javascript that will open the new window.

However, most browsers will kill a new window called in this manner (i.e. popup blocker).

You would be better off, if possible, by opening the link to your action in a new window from the start;

```
@Html.ActionLink("New report", "New", "Report", null, new {target = "_blank"})
```

**Edit**

I can see from your action, that it is probably a form that creates the report; you can also use the attribute `target='_blank'` on a form as well.

Comment: thanks Matt, yeah this is for showing report. actually, i have menu report. but now my boss tell me to do something like, whenever the controller do New action it will show report in a new window. and now, i got confused how to get the value that i added. see edit

Comment: Yes, you could use the actionlink sample to create your menu link.  This just opens the new window *before* calling the action, which can then save the data and open up the report view.