# Open URL in a new tab from MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

How do i open an URL in a new tab / window from MVC controller based on success condition .Any way i can achieve it through the help of c# code without having to write javascript ?

Comment: What does your code currently look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC 3 Controller Action and Open New Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790355/asp-net-mvc-3-controller-action-and-open-new-window)

Comment: @TheLazyChap This is what i am trying achieve from the controller 

<!-- language: c# -->
 If (user.selectedmethod == "Login")
{
 return JavaScript("<script>window.open('http://www.google.com');</script>");
}

Comment: @Yoda Why do not select the answer so that people try the best answer?

Answer (score 13):

This cannot be done from the controller , but rather from your razor View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "Action", new {controller="ControllerName"}, new {target="_blank"})
```

Comment: This is what i am trying achieve - User clicks on button and it hits a controller where it checks for some filters and if it succeeds it should open a URL example "http://google.com in a new window 

<!-- language: c# --> 

If (user.selectedmethod == "Login")

 { return JavaScript("<script>window.open('google.com');</script>"); }

<!-- language: c# -->

Comment: Why you dont use JQuery or javascript then what is the pb with that? You can do an ajax call and validate the data then navigate a new window based on that ?

Answer (score 3):

**Calling URL from Controller:**

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Home");
```

**Calling Action Method from View using HTML Button or Image:**

When creating a link to a controller action in ASP.NET MVC, using the generic ActionLink method is preferable, because it allows for strongly typed links that are refactoring friendly.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Home", new { id = item.ID })
```

However, what if we want to have an image that links to an action? You might think that you could combine the ActionLink and Image and Button helpers like this:

**Using Button:**

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Home",new { Model.ID })';return false;">Detail</button>
    
<input type="button" title="Delete" value="D" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { id = item.ID })'" />
```

**Using Image:**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { id = item.ID })" title="Edit">
```