# Redirect to an external website JavaScript with POST method

Tags: javascript, submit, target

With this JavaScript linker.js:
I want to open a new window and redirect to a webpage outside the current website, Here is my code:

```
    deps  = ['jquery'];
    define (deps, function($) {
    var linker = {
        'link' : function(ortholog,link) {
            $form = $('<form>');
            $form.attr("method","POST");
            $form.attr("action",link);
            $form.attr("target","_blank");
            $input = $("<input>");
            $input.attr("type","hidden");
            $input.attr("value",ortholog);
            $form.appendChild($input);

            $form.submit();
        }
        //return linker();
    }
    return linker;
});
```

I am facing problem similar to [url.Action open link in new window on ASP.NET MVC Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381949/url-action-open-link-in-new-window-on-asp-net-mvc-page)

How can I move out of my current website?

Comment: The value of `action` will be a `Event` object. `action+ortholog` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: In my code link is the path that I want it to redirect to and ortholog is an id which was intended to be concatenated with the above path and form a full URL.

Comment: So maybe it should be `window.open(link+ortholog)`

Comment: I have tried that too, but I end up with a URL concatenating my present website URL and the path (to which I wanted it to redirect to ) similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381949/url-action-open-link-in-new-window-on-asp-net-mvc-page

Comment: I'm having a real hard time figuring out what you're tring to do. `$form.attr("action", link)` means that `link` is where you want the form submitted to. How can it also be the URL you want to redirect to? And why doesn't the form you're creating have any input fields?

Comment: Yes I realized my mistake with input field, (new to web programming). This is how my understanding goes about action(maybe terribly wrong), say I want to redirect to www.yahoo.com I would write $form.attr("action",www.yahoo.com);

Comment: I still don't understand what all this form stuff is for. Why don't you just do `window.open("www.yahoo.com")`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56450/discussion-between-user2998764-and-barmar).